# T-SQL - Include table name (or alias) concatenated with column name in result set?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datatable

Using SSMS when joining 3+ tables and using `SELECT *`, I'm wondering if there is an easy way (dynamic) to include the table name & column name in the result set without having to type out all the desired columns.

For example:

```
Table1
Table2
Table3
```

```sql
SELECT *
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON t2.keyA = t1.keyA
LEFT JOIN Table3 t3 ON t2.keyB = t3.keyB
```

Trying to produce output like

```
Table1-Column1, Table2-Column1, Table3-Column1
```

OR

```
t1.Column1, t2.Column1, t3.Column1
```

Comment: No, there isn't. You need to properly define your columns and their aliases. You *could* use Dynamic SQL, but unless you are well versed with the language, and know all the considerations that come with it, you shouldn't be using it. And if you were well versed with the language, you'd know that the correct answer is to write out your queries properly.

Comment: There are SSMS plugins which expand wildcards.  I have one from ApexSQL Refactor which costs a license fee.

Comment: @larnu - If the query's purpose is ad-hoc or researching something quickly it doesn't make sense to waste time typing out 50+ columns from multiple joined tables.

Comment: If it's an ad-hoc and quick solution, having the same name won't be an issue, @Seth , as you would fix it in whatever you're likely copying to data to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a lot of column, there's is an easy way to do it, but not dynamically. If you have only a few columns, doesn't worth a try and do it manually.

Take a look at theses two methods : https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/06/06/sql-server-tricks-to-replace-select-with-column-names-sql-in-sixty-seconds-017-video/

First method (drag'n'drop columns) isn't useful in your case cause we need to have all column aligned on different lines. The second (generating the create table script) is the one we need.

Generate the create table for table1 and copy-paste the columns needed from table1 into your query, and repeat for table2 and table3. Make sure they are all aligned in the same editor column.

Then, "the magic trick", simply press and hold the Alt key, click between the coma and the first letter of the first column name of t1 and drag to select the lines between the first column of t1 to the last column of t1. Type "t1.".   That's it. repeat for t2 and t3.

This is not sql-server related, nor SSMS, but works with any decent editor supporting multiline editing.

Comment: Thanks, this post is useful and appreciated!